# mkdir error in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, mkdir

The following is a fragment of a bash script that I'm running under cygwin on Windows:

```
deployDir=/cygdrive/c/Temp/deploy

timestamp=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`
deployDir=${deployDir}/$timestamp

if [ ! -d "$deployDir" ]; then
    echo "making dir $deployDir"
    mkdir -p $deployDir
fi
```

This produces output such as:

```
making dir /cygdrive/c/Temp/deploy/2010-04-30_11:47:58
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
```

However, if I type `/cygdrive/c/Temp/deploy/2010-04-30_11:47:58` on the command-line it succeeds, why does the same command not work in the script?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Change:

```
mkdir -p $deploydir
```

to

```
mkdir -p "$deployDir"
```

Like most Unix shells (maybe even all of them), Bourne (Again) Shell (sh/bash) is case-sensitive.  The dir var is called `deployDir` (mixed-case) everywhere except for the `mkdir` command, where it is called `deploydir` (all lowercase).  Since `deploydir` (all lowercase) is a considered distinct variable from `deployDir` (mixed-case) and `deplydir` (all lowercase) has never had a value assigned to it, the value of `deploydir` (all lowercase) is empty string ("").

Without the quotes (`mkdir $deploydir`), the line effectively becomes `mkdir` (just the command without the required operand), thus the error `mkdir: missing operand`.

With the quotes (`mkdir "$deploydir"`), the line effectively becomes `mkdir ""` (the command to make a directory with the illegal directory name of empty string), thus the error `mkdir: cannot create directory`'.

Using the form with quotes (`mkdir "$deployDir"`) is recommended in case the target directory name includes spaces.

Comment: I had thi sproblem and the fix was really simple. Remember not to leave spaces between variable "=" and assigned variable value.

Answer (score 10):

Change:

```
mkdir -p $deploydir
```

to

```
mkdir -p "$deploydir"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have colons in file names on Windows, for obvious reasons.

Comment: That's true. But who said anything about Windows?

Comment: @Dennis: The question? "[...] running under cygwin on Windows"?

Comment: Oops, back to kindergarten for me. However, Cygwin does support colons in filenames.