# Unable to create a directory using mkdir

Tags: bash, mkdir

I installed Openfoam a couple of days ago . I could follow the instructions given [here](http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php)
without facing any major issues. However, when I run the command `$mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN` today, I am getting this error: `mkdir: missing operand`. I also tried `mkdir -p "$FOAM_RUN"` (it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743673/mkdir-error-in-bash-script/2743818#2743818)). Even this failed with the error message `` mkdir: cannot create directory `': No such file or directory ``. /.bashrc file is updated as per the instructions given on Openfoam website.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that your variable `$FOAM_RUN` is not defined.  You can confirm that by executing the command: `echo $FOAM_RUN`

Comment: `echo $FOAM_RUN` returns an empty line. How do I define it? But, the same command did work just a couple of days ago!

Comment: I must have worked fine because the variable may have been defined while you built the system.  You may need to add the statement to define the variable in your initialization file (depending on shell).

Answer (score 0):

Like @unxnut said, your variable is not defined.
To define the variable, you just type:

```
FOAM_RUN=dir_name
```

then your above command will create a directory called "dir_name", or whatever you assign FOAM_RUN.

Hope this helps.